# Problem viewing a pdf file in a shiny app

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

To view a pdf file and my shiny app, I use the following code on the server side, which everyone recommends:

```
 output$pdf_info_exper <- renderUI({      
   selected_Exper = input$select_data     
   pdf_path = get_pdfExper (selected_Exper,base_dir='.')    
   tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src= pdf_path, type="application/pdf")
   #tags$embed( src=pdf_path, style="height:600px; width:100%", type="application/pdf")
 })
```

The problem is that when I do it, it skips my app adobe reader directly and I haven't embedded it in my app.
when run the app in the browser if the pdf is embedded in the app, I understand,I would like to know how to embed the pdf viewer in my app without the adoba/reader jumping...

I accept any suggestion, thanks....

Comment: Have you tried on a simplified version of your App?

Comment: Some time ago I opened an issue on the RStudio Github repository to ask for PDF support in the viewer, because it has not. However I'm not sure whether I tried with iframe. But it's quite possible this is due to this limitation of RStudio viewer.

Comment: The function that I have written is the simplest,  You just have to put the pdfs in the www directory and this function in server of shiny app.
 

I'll try to see if the psf plugin can be obtained from the user's browser. Although I don't think you have permissions...
I have tried with tags$embed but with the same result. Skip the user's pdf reader  
If you want to set up a group for the development of this problem, count on me...

Comment: The ideal, as in other applications with other programming languages, is to maintain its own viewer. It makes no sense to force the user to download the pdf file to read it and know its content.
The object should be displayed but inside the app as a viewer. Create a widget that is a document viewer, at least of type pdf.